# Digital gate in LTspice not all availabe and no generic NOR gate?

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice, simulation

I tried to find a NOR gate in LTspice but seems there is only Or gate with multiple inputs. I tried also to import a third party but could not find a generic NOR gate

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find this a very lazy approach. All you had to do was select the component and the preview would have answered your question. Instead, you took time to screenshot, edit, post a question, and wait for an answer. -1.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, the screenshot shows they'd already placed an OR gate in their schematic and had a chance to look at it. On the other hand, this is all explained in the LTSpice help files, so ....

Comment: @ThePhoton You're right, but that only makes it worse.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen. Actually, after I watched some tutorials where all of them show there are plenty of gate , I showed the screen shot so you can see that I have only one OR gate with multiple inputs, while I want to have only two input as my circuit is getting bigger and using the one provided does not help me

Comment: @Yaakov, read the help file. It also explains what to do if you don't want to use all 5 inputs.

Comment: @Yaakov And did you try, at least out of curiosity, to open up the manual? For example at `LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. ...`.

Comment: That one I haven't tried. I am on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LTSpice logic gates have two outputs. One is the "true" output and one is "complementary" (meaning inverted).

[image]

If you want a NOR gate, just place an "OR" gate and connect to the complementary output.